# formatting a rotated table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, vertical-alignment, rotating

I am trying to create a rotated table in the following way, which is almost what I want:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3} % onecolumn (second format)
\smartqed % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}

%\captionof{table}{Integrated background levels in the 2-10 keV energy band. Numbers are in units of $[\times10^{-3}~p~cm^{-2}~s^{-1}~keV^{-1}]$}
\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}

\begin{tabularx}{1.2\textheight}{X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X}
\label{tab:2}

  Background [2-12 keV]     & 250 $\mu m$ Kapton    & 250 $\mu m$ Kapton + 10 $\mu m$ W     &  250 $\mu m$ Kapton + 20 $\mu m$ Bi + 10 $\mu m$ W    & 250 $\mu m$ Kapton + 250 $\mu m$ SiC + 10 $\mu m$ W   & 250 $\mu m$ Kapton + 300 $\mu m$ $Si_{3}N_{4}$ + 10 $\mu m$ W     &  10 $\mu m$ W + 300 $\mu m$ $Si_{3}N_{4}$     & 250 $\mu m$ Kapton + 1.3 $mm$ $Si_{3}N_{4}$   & 250 $\mu m$ Kapton +  20 $\mu m$ Bi   & 250 $\mu m$ Kapton + 1 $mm$ SiC \\
    \hline
Total               & 10            & 7.6                   & 8.8                           & 8.4                           & 8.1                                   & 7.8                       & 7.4                       & 8                 & 7.3 \\
\hline
Photons             & 2         & 1.7                   & 1.7                           & 1.4                           & 1.3                                   & 1                     & 1.2                       & 1.9                   & 1.4 \\
\hline
Electrons           & 8         & 5.9                   & 7.1                           & 7                         & 6.8                                   & 6.8                       & 6.2                       & 6.1                   & 5.9 \\
\hline
Lines?              & E.P.          & W: 8.4 keV, 9.6 keV           & Bi: 10.8 keV                      & No                            & No                                    & Si:1.72 keV                   & No                        & Bi:10.8 keV               & E.P. \\

  \end{tabularx}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

I would like so solve a few issues however:

- I would like the cells to be aligned to the center (both horizontally and vertically)
- I need to insert the commented caption above the table, which is currently generating several errors
- any other suggestion to make the table look more pleasant is welcomed

I have searched a long time without any results, I really need some help from more experienced latex users

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't `svjour3` package, so instead with it I use `article` with page layout determined by `geometry` package. For rotate table  rather use package `rotating`. Its environment `sidewaystable` rotate page content and also center it on tex area. Rotating is simpler, if you limit table width to `\textheight`. As you can see from table image, this is suficient for table width. Its extension for 20% is not smart idea, table probably will protrude page size.

Off-topic: table will look better if cells contents is ragged right (flush to left). I didn't do further possible improvements like (i) delete vertical rules, (ii) use `toprile`, `midlerule` and `\bottomrule` from package `booktabs`, (iii) increase row separation with for example `\renewcommand\arraystreatch{1.2}`, etc:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%[smallextended]{svjour3} % onecolumn (second format)
%\smartqed % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{adjustbox, rotating}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[showframe,% don't use this option in real document
            margin=25mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

%\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\captionof{table}{Integrated background levels in the 2-10 keV energy band. Numbers are in units of $[\times10^{-3}~p~cm^{-2}~s^{-1}~keV^{-1}]$}
\begin{tabularx}{1\textheight}{L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L}
\label{tab:2}

Background [2-12 keV]     & 250 $\mu m$ Kapton    & 250 $\mu m$ Kapton + 10 $\mu m$ W     &  250 $\mu m$ Kapton + 20 $\mu m$ Bi + 10 $\mu m$ W    & 250 $\mu m$ Kapton + 250 $\mu m$ SiC + 10 $\mu m$ W   & 250 $\mu m$ Kapton + 300 $\mu m$ $Si_{3}N_{4}$ + 10 $\mu m$ W     &  10 $\mu m$ W + 300 $\mu m$ $Si_{3}N_{4}$     & 250 $\mu m$ Kapton + 1.3 $mm$ $Si_{3}N_{4}$   & 250 $\mu m$ Kapton +  20 $\mu m$ Bi   & 250 $\mu m$ Kapton + 1 $mm$ SiC \\
    \hline
Total               & 10            & 7.6                   & 8.8                           & 8.4                           & 8.1                                   & 7.8                       & 7.4                       & 8                 & 7.3 \\
\hline
Photons             & 2         & 1.7                   & 1.7                           & 1.4                           & 1.3                                   & 1                     & 1.2                       & 1.9                   & 1.4 \\
\hline
Electrons           & 8         & 5.9                   & 7.1                           & 7                         & 6.8                                   & 6.8                       & 6.2                       & 6.1                   & 5.9 \\
\hline
Lines?              & E.P.          & W: 8.4 keV, 9.6 keV           & Bi: 10.8 keV                      & No                            & No                                    & Si:1.72 keV                   & No                        & Bi:10.8 keV               & E.P. \\

  \end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```